# Macbook Pro keeps getting falsely black-holed by ISP(Building's) firewall?

Tags: wifi, internet, firewall

I live in a building that provides internet (both wired and wifi), and has its own infrastructure. This has been going on since Friday, and is driving me insane. Here's the details:

Macbook Pro Early 2013 15" Retina running the latest Sierra public build.
Within a few minutes of joining the building's Wi-fi, my MacBook loses all internet connectivity. It stays connected to the wifi, but no packets in our out to the internet. I tried http/s, icmp, imap/smtp, SIP, every port and protocol I tested don't return. Pages don't load, browsers just hang there with the blue progress bar about 1/8th of the way filled in.
The troubleshooting I've done:

- When this happens, if I spoof my MAC address, I'll get a new IP and regain connectivity for a few minutes, until it all happens again
- If I connect wired - same deal
- To rule out some insane mac collision situation, I connected a router and enabled NAT. When my MacBook joins that router's wifi, the router and every device behind it lose internet connectivity
- If I tunnel using a VPN service, MacBook stays connected indefinitely. This has been my workaround, and also a smoking gun to point at their infrastructure - by obscuring my traffic, they no longer block me.
- Installed Little Snitch - no abnormal connections to suspicious places that I can tell. Only system processes to Apple servers, and if I'm browsing, then the browser to various web resources.

I'm basically out of ideas on how to fix this or even troubleshoot further. From my troubleshooting, I can't put the blame anywhere but squarely on their firewalls making some sort of false positive match.

The support folks claim that it can't be the firewall, because if it blocks your MAC, it blocks it for good until an admin unblocks it, whereas in my case if I shut the device down for roughly an hour, it'll be unblocked.

Any ideas on where to go from here, or similar experiences?

Thanks!

Comment: You're going to have to take this issue up with whomever controls the buildings connectivity and is blocking your device.

Comment: I agree. Mostly want to 1) check my logic and 2) see if anyone's had a similar experience.